# Pass Map keys as argument to Java varags method

Tags: scala

I have a LinkedHashMap

`val groupedKey = new mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,String]`

I want to pass in the keys and values from this to the method in Java which accepts varags String.

`javamethod1keys(String ... )`
`javamethod1values(String ... )`

How will I do this

`val labels=groupedKey.keySet.toArray`

`javamethod(labels)`

This does not work, I also tried mkString method

Comment: Try this: `javamethod(groupedKey.keys.toSeq:_*)`

Answer (score 0):

The `:_*` operator really does the trick.

I have tested it on JDK code example like this:

```
object Test {
  val a: Seq[String] = ???
  new javax.management.ImmutableDescriptor(a:_*)
}
```